# End of Video Banner Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using code below to run video in my banner on Squarespace. Would like it so that when video ends banner loads banner image. Can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Btw, totally new to scripting.

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).bind("load", function() {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        } else {
          var banner = $('#pageWrapper img').first();
          if (banner.length === 0)
            banner = $('.banner-thumbnail-wrapper > #thumbnail > img').first();
          if (banner.length === 0)
            banner = $('#parallax-images img').first();
          if (banner.length === 0)
            banner = $('.has-main-image img').first();
          if (banner.length === 0)
              banner = $('#page-thumb img').first();
          var url = "VIDEOHERE";
          banner.hide();
          $('<video class="bannerVideo" autoplay="" preload><source src="' + url + '" type="video/mp4"></video>').insertAfter(banner);
          adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
          setTimeout(function() {
            adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
          }, 2000);
          $(window, banner).resize(function() {
            adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
            setTimeout(function() {
              adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
            }, 200);
          });
        }
        function adjustBanner (video, banner) {
          video.css({
            height: banner.css('height'),
            width: banner.css('width'),
            top: banner.css('top'),
            left: banner.css('left'),
            position: 'relative',
            'object-fit': 'inherit'
          });
        }
      });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `onended` event listener after you have inserted the video.

```
var video = querySelector('.bannerVideo');
video.onended = function() {
  // Display Image
  adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, where exactly do I add this code. Just started using programming language so bit of a struggle to get it right. Thank you in advance.